# JAVA program and my distance isn't adding

Tags: java, computer-science

```
------K-Nearest-Neighbor Prediction Program---

The values you entered are :  sunny cool high true no

Comparring the values :     sunny      hot     high    FALSE dist = 0 and play =  no 
Comparring the values :     sunny      hot     high     TRUE dist = 0 and play =  no 
Comparring the values :  overcast      hot     high    FALSE dist = 0 and play = yes 
Comparring the values :     rainy     mild     high    FALSE dist = 0 and play = yes 
Comparring the values :     rainy     cool   normal    FALSE dist = 0 and play = yes 
Comparring the values :     rainy     cool   normal     TRUE dist = 0 and play =  no 
Comparring the values :  overcast     cool   normal     TRUE dist = 0 and play = yes 
Comparring the values :     sunny     mild     high    FALSE dist = 0 and play =  no 
Comparring the values :     sunny     cool   normal    FALSE dist = 0 and play = yes 
Comparring the values :     rainy     mild   normal    FALSE dist = 0 and play = yes
Comparring the values :     sunny     mild   normal     TRUE dist = 0 and play = yes 
Comparring the values :  overcast     mild     high     TRUE dist = 0 and play = yes 
Comparring the values :  overcast      hot   normal    FALSE dist = 0 and play = yes 
Comparring the values :     rainy     mild     high     TRUE dist = 0 and play =  no 
Given the data, the prediction to play is:  no
```

My problem is that the distance isn't adding.
It's suppose to go down in descending order in: 2,1,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,4,2,2,4,2    but instead I have all zeroes.

Here's my code.....:::

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class lab2
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    throws FileNotFoundException
    {

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));

        String queryOutlook = "  sunny  ";
        String queryHumidity = " high ";
        String queryTempurature = " hot ";
        String queryWind = " true ";
        String queryPlay = " play ";
        String outlook = null;
        String humidity = null;
        String tempurature = null;
        String wind = null;
        String play = null;
        int dist = 0;
        System.out.print("------K-Nearest-Neighbor Prediction Program---\n\n");
        System.out.print("The values you entered are :  ");
        outlook = input.next();
        tempurature = input.next();
        humidity = input.next();
        wind = input.next();
        play = input.next();
        while(in.hasNext())
        {
            outlook = in.next();
            tempurature = in.next();
            humidity = in.next();
            wind = in.next();
            play = in.next();
            dist = 0;
            if (outlook.equalsIgnoreCase(queryOutlook) )
                dist++;
            if (humidity.equalsIgnoreCase(queryHumidity) )
                dist++;
            if (tempurature.equalsIgnoreCase(queryTempurature) )
                dist++;
            if (wind.equalsIgnoreCase(queryWind) )
                dist++;
            if (play.equalsIgnoreCase(queryPlay) )
                dist++;

            System.out.printf("\r\nComparring the values :  %8s %8s %8s %8s", outlook, tempurature, humidity, wind);
            System.out.printf(" dist = %1d and play = %3s ",dist,play);
        }
        System.out.printf("\nGiven the data, the prediction to play is: %3s \n",play);
        in.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Sample output: Comparring the values: sunny hot high FALSE dist = 2 and play = no

Answer (score 2):

Scanner ignores whitespace by default when grabbing tokens, so the .equals is failing because there are spaces in your constants.

Comment: ok I got it to add them to something other than zero, but my numbers are still wrong

Comment: it reads with numbers: 3,4,2,1,0,1,1,2,1,0,2,2,1,2 when it should be 2,1,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,4,2,2,4,2

Comment: based on what's above, 3 and 4 look right. I haven't checked further than that.

Comment: ok, do you think the profesor may of made an error with the sample output?